# figure is in subsection but it goes to subsection

Tags: graphics, floats, sectioning, positioning, ieeeconf

I need your help in solving the followings:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}
...
\subsubsection{C}
\begin{figure}[h]
   \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width = 4.5cm]{s.jpg}
      \label{fig:s}
   \end{minipage}
   \hspace{1cm}
   \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width =  4.5cm]{d.jpg}
      \label{fig:d}
   \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

yet I get that this figures shows right before the `\subsubsection{C} (in the subsection).
And I am working with 2 column mode article.
I have tried using`placeins`and`htp` for figures but it did not do anything meaning that it has not show under the desired subsection.

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you don't want your image to float, then don't use `figure`, because that's a floating environment.

Comment: in particular using `[h]` makes this more likely to happen as it means not t(op) not b(ottom) and not p(age float) so it gives latex almost nowhere that it can place the figure. However if you want figures to stay in sections see the `placeins` package.  (but still use `[htp]` not `[h]`)

Comment: `[!htp]` mitigates this issue further

Comment: if `\subsubsection` is defined as a run-in heading, latex will be looking for text when the `figure` command is issued.  add some invisible content to get out of that situation.  `\leavemode` is recommended for similar situations when such a heading is followed directly by a list.

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 5):

A common misunderstanding is that figures or tables *have to* be placed in an environment of the same name to let them float away. They can be placed `in situ` (given enough space is available), just dropping the `figure` or `table` environment.

If a caption is needed (the `\label` command in the MWE is useless without `\caption`, then `\captionof` by the `caption` package can be applied, however there are the starred versions `\caption*` and  `\captionof*` that do not provide numbering and entries to the `List of Figures`.

By the way: The name of the class is `IEEEconf`, not `ieeeconf`. The lower case variant could lead to problems if it is used on file systems/operating systems that distinguish between lower and uppercase file names.

Personal comment: As a teacher I write worksheets which should not extend one single page very often, at most two pages, from a teaching point of typography, it is not a good idea to let tables and figures float away to the next page when you have to transport information right on the spot.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{IEEEconf}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{C}
Foo


\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\columnwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width = 3cm]{beeduck}%
  \captionof{figure}{First figure}%
  \label{fig:c}%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\columnwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width =  3cm]{beeduck}%
  \captionof{figure}{Second figure}%
  \label{fig:d}%
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The two, side-by-side, minipages should probably be placed inside a single `center` environment. It might also be a good idea to provid a bit of whitespace between the minipages.

Comment: @Mico: Most likely, yes. I am no fan of `minipage` actually. I use `tabular` most time to align images ;-)

Comment: I just noticed that since the `IEEEconf` document class uses a two-column layout, using `\texwidth` instead of `\columwidth` is going to make the material protrude massively into the second column. Better to use `\columnwidth` when specifying the widths of the minipages.

Comment: @Mico: Done, thanks (Isn't `\textwidth` adapted to `\columnwidth` automatically?)

Comment: I believe that in a two-column document, `\textwidth` is the full width of the text block (i.e., two columns plus the space between the columns), whereas `\linewidth` by default equals `\columnwidth`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was the other way round. I'll have to delete this information from my brain hard disk ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses the `[h!]` position specifier to direct LaTeX to make the `figure` environment non-floating. Of course, this method won't work if there's not enough space remaining in the column to actually insert the two side-by-side images and their captions.

Instead of absolute widths for the minipages and images, I'd use relative widths, e.g., relative to the overall width of the column.

Note that the `caption` package should not be loaded if the `IEEEconf` document class is in use.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{IEEEconf}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}   % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{lipsum}           % filler text
\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{2}       % just for this example
\setcounter{subsection}{4}    % just for this example
\setcounter{subsubsection}{2} % just for this example

\lipsum[2] % filler text

\subsubsection{C}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \dots

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\columnwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{c.jpg}
  \caption{Caption of first figure}
  \label{fig:c}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{\fill} % some spacing between the minipages
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\columnwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{d.jpg}
  \caption{Caption of second figure}
  \label{fig:d}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: My images are nicer :-P (+1)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - *Much* nicer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Writing on my mobile phone:

Use the package **float** and then use **[H]** instead of **[h]** as the placement option.

Comment: God kills a kitten every time somebody uses a Float Barrier

Comment: @Holene: Blame God then, not me :)